# How to prevent matching two routes with react-router v4?

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

I have the following two routes: `/items` and `/items/buy`.

Each route corresponds to a Tab in a single view. Both routes are rendered with an exact prop, but still, two tabs are being marked as active when navigating to `/items/buy`.

I already tried using `withRouter`, but I noticed changing `/items` to `/items/sell` fixes the problem, but I don't wanna have that route.

I understand rrv4 is matching the first part of my route `/items` and the other route too `/items/buy`, but I think that shouldn't be happening if I'm using `exact`. Any clues on why this is happening?

Ahh I forgot to say I am already using a Switch.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was wrapping a NavItem with a LinkContainer and the LinkContainer did not have an exact prop. Adding the exact prop solved the issue!

Answer (score 22):

You need to put your routes in a `<Switch>` component. The switch will only render the first route that matches.

```
import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
  <Route exact path="/items" component={SomeComponent} />
  <Route exact path="/items/buy" component={SomeOtherComponent} />
  <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```