# Multiple components getting rendered for single route with react-router v4?

Tags: reactjs, path, routes, react-router-dom

So, i'm trying to understand why 2 routes are rendered at the same time in this case :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, NavLink, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import './Blog.css';
import Posts from './Posts/Posts';
import NewPost from './NewPost/NewPost';
import FullPost from './FullPost/FullPost'

class Blog extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div className="Blog">
                <header>
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><NavLink to="/" exact>Home</NavLink></li> 
                            <li><NavLink to= "/new-post">New Post</NavLink></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </header>
                <Route path="/" exact component={Posts} />
                <Route path="/new-post" exact  component={NewPost} />
                <Route path="/:id" exact component={FullPost} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Blog;
```

When i click on **New Post** instead of seeing just *NewPost component* i also see in addition *FullPost component*. I can not understand how /newpost path and /:id path are the same in this case. I know that this problem can be solved with Switch , however i'd like to understand why is this happening at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because, when you are navigating to `/new-post`, two route paths are getting matched. When you write: `path="/:id"`, id (an optional route param) can be anything, a number, string etc, so id will become `/new-post`, and it will render `FullPost` also, That's why.

Solution is, use [Switch](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Switch) (it will always render the component with first matched path) from `react-router` to avoid the matching of multiple paths, so that only one component will get rendered on route path match. Like this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/" exact component={Posts} />
  <Route path="/new-post" exact  component={NewPost} />
  <Route path="/:id" exact component={FullPost} />
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your routes in a  component. The switch will only render the first route that matches.

```
<Switch>
 <Route path="/" exact component={Posts} />
 <Route path="/new-post" exact  component={NewPost} />
 <Route path="/:id" exact component={FullPost} />
</Switch>
```

This answer is in [How to prevent matching two routes with react-router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958758/how-to-prevent-matching-two-routes-with-react-router-v4)

When you don't use Switch you match both routes because /new-post is also considered as an id parameter by your router.